# I have a CreateSpace ISBN but want to Publish a New Edition through another Publisher

Tags: self-publishing, isbn

I have a CreateSpace-Assigned ISBN but I want to publish a collection of my books that are currently on CreateSpace through another publisher using a different title but some of the same material?

Comment: Perhaps you can clarify what you're asking? Have placed on hold for now.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to have a new ISBN for the new edition. Every edition or variation of a book must have its own unique ISBN. If you publish an e-book, print, and audio version, then each of those will have their own ISBNs. Also, if you publish the exact same e-book on different platforms, such as Kindle and Nook, you will need a separate ISBN for each platform.

Comment: +1: And I'd just add that the technical reason why a different ISBN should be assigned through different platforms is that they use different file formats, or even if they deliver the content in the same file format they use different DRM systems. If different platforms deliver the same format and the same DRM (or no DRM), then they can share an ISBN.